# How can I make stdin always get consumed?

Tags: bash, stdin

Some programs do not read from stdin (such as `dmesg` or `adb logcat`). I usually press <kbd>Return</kbd> a few times to provide a separation between log lines. When I interrupt the command directly in the shell, everything works satisfactory.

However, when the programs terminate themselves (because the connection for `adb logcat` gets lost for example), the shell starts processing all lines I have entered. This usually looks like this:

```
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ # I broke something here
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ TODO LOOK AT THIS
bash: TODO: command not found
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ 
user@host$ # adb is about to get killed...
user@host$
```

As you can understand, having Bash execute all these lines is quite useless and shifts the last remaining output. Is there a way to consume stdin even when the process terminates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
dmesg -Hw; read -t .01 -d ""
```

This command will (after `dmesg` has terminated) run the Bash built-in `read` to consume all input (no delimiter instead of a newline, `-d ""`). The `-t .01` argument causes the read command to timeout after 0.01 seconds so that the command returns quickly.